# Galaxy S2 through USB won't connect to my Mac?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, connection-issues, macos

I have an Android Evo, and it connects to my Mac just fine when connecting the USB cable. I can access the entire phone data.

However, my wife's Samsung Galaxy 2's data can't be accessed on my Mac, even though the Mac recognizes the USB connection. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If phone data/photos is all you're after, I suggest using [Airdroid](http://airdroid.com/) instead. No wires required, and will work on any computer.

If you're really set on using the cord, you may be missing GS2 drivers. You'll need to install [Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/) from Samsung.